# Por quanto tempo durou e qual o padrão por trás da nasalação de oxítonas terminadas em i?

Tags: fonologia, mudanças-históricas

No Português, certas palavras nativas oxítonas terminadas em i foram nasalizadas: *si → sim*, *mi → mim*, *assi → assim*, *mai → mãe*. Porém, outras não foram: *ti → ti*, *aqui → aqui*, *ali → ali*.
Qual é, se é que há, o padrão fonético por trás dessas transformações?

Além disso, por quanto tempo durou essa transformação?
Pois há palavras mais recentes ao vocabulário, de origem tupi, que a sofreram: *tupiniki → tupiniquim* (tribo nativa do Brasil, atualmente é sinônimo para “Brasileiro”), *capi → capim* (grama),  *mandubi → amendoim* (por influência de *amêndoa*), *waxini → guaxinim* (mamífero americano).

Comment: Muita informação se encontra aqui: https://repositorio.uac.pt/bitstream/10400.3/1098/1/VogaisNasaisNasalizadasMACM.pdf

Comment: Segundo o "Dicionário de tupi antigo" (Eduardo A. Navarro), são "tupinikĩ", "kapi’i", "mandubi" e "gûasunĩ" (onde apóstrofo significa /ʔ/ e circunflexo semivogal); comparar "aîpĩ/aîpi’ĩ", "kupi’ĩ", "mirĩ". Logo só "amendoim" e "capim" (cf "capivara") são exemplos mesmo, e talvez variantes incomuns como "jabutim". Mas não acho que tenham relação com a nasalização das palavras mais velhas "sim" (La. sīc), "alecrim" e "marfim" (Ár. al-ʔiklīl, ʕaẓm al-fīl, segundo o Wikcionário). E estas por sua vez parecem não ter relação com "mim, mãe, muito", que já iniciavam com nasal.

Comment: E compare com o espanhol "marfil", que deveria ser "(al)malfil". Seguindo a forma da palavra árabe, talvez houvesse "aleclil", com três "l". Dissimilações ou corruptelas? Vendo as etimologias árabes, há vários outros exemplos em que uma letra é trocada, perdida ou adicionada; não vejo uma regra.